# How to capture transaction data generated from PayPal smart button payment with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to implement PayPal payment using a smart button with a script provided by PayPal:

```
<div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_CLIENT_ID&currency=CAD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'horizontal',
          label: 'pay',
          
        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"description":"Package delivery","amount":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":1}}]
          });
        },

/*        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
        }, */
            onApprove: function(data) {
              return fetch('/my-server/capture-paypal-transaction.php', {
                headers: {
                  'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  orderID: data.orderID
                })
              }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
              }).then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction funds captured from ' + details.payer_given_name);
              })
            },
        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

I replaced the commented code with the function below that suggests one can link to a file on the server to process the returned data.

I can find no clear instruction on how this can be done with this PayPal-generated button and all the git examples relating to IPN is either outdated or has deprecated PHP code such as references to magic-quotes.

Is there an example PHP file on capturing the transaction data from a smart button?

Answer (score 0):

Your example mixes a client-side `actions.order.create()` with a fetch to do a server-side capture. This mixing should not be done. Perform both steps from the server (or neither if not using a server-side language like PHP)

So, create two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: I am really unclear. Am I supposed to have the SDK on my server to implement capturing the data? The code in my original question is that from a generator on PayPal, that is with the commented "onApprove:" block that I replaced with the one that you explain incorrectly mixes the fetch. From the example in your last link, in the onCreate block `return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/'` where does that path lead to? Is that the page with the button? This from onApprove, I don't grasp: `return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/'`

Comment: My data is taken from an HTML table rendered by PHP, so that the 'amount' I take from a `var amt = "<?php echo $thePackage->cost();?>"` and  my createOrder looks like: `purchase_units: [{"description":"Package delivery <?php echo $thePackage->track;?>","amount":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":amt}}]`. I don't have a form that's posted.

Comment: Create two routes on your server that implement the necessary calls. You can either use the server-side SDK, or direct HTTPS calls from the server. The documentation's examples for PHP in the link are with the SDK.

Comment: what are the routes? How are they created? I am not familiar with PayPal's set up beyond what is configured in my account. In the past any IPN operation I used was something provided in a shopping app. This trying to request a payment from a user for a service and recording the transaction in my database is new to me an the documentation isn't procedural: To do X, first do Y. To me it seems all fragments.

Comment: Routes are paths on your site that return a response. Paths to a PHP file, for example. The data returned must be in JSON format, with no other HTML or text.

Comment: So In the example at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server, what does the first path contain? I assume the the second path would process what was returned to insert in the database by I see that `data.orderID` is in the URL meaning such a path doesn't exist: `return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/'`. Is that a _GET url?

Comment: Use a different path structure if you want. A GET string would begin with `?`. Your server must recognize the paths and route them to the correct place, that is why they are called routes.